# regex with at least 4 characters, 1 number, 1 letter, excluding spaces and special characters

Tags: regex

The whole string contains at least 4 characters (numbers and letters, excluding spaces)
The string contains at least 1 letter
The string contains at least 1 number

Example:
The regex should NOT match:

1. 1
2. a
3. 12
4. ab
5. 12a
6. 123
7. aaa
8. 1 1a
9. 11 a

The Regex Should match:

- 123a
- 1234a
- 123a abcd1
- 123a 1234
- Ab 123
- 1234 abcd
- 12 ab
- 12ab ab12 ab321
- 123 a

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=(.*[\da-zA-Z]){4}).{4,}$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bW2jB4/2)